# Game code breaking when setting variable

Tags: javascript, variables

This game code seems fine, but it's not working:

```
//Get canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Capture keypresses
var keys = [];
document.onKeyDown = function (e) {keys[e.keyCode] = true;};
document.onKeyUp = function (e) {keys[e.keyCode] = false;};

//Set game variables
var characters;
characters.charList = [];
var player = {};

//Character constructor
function Character (Name, Strength, Speed, Intelligence, Reflexes, Age, Height, Weight, Weapon, UsesMagic, MagicType, Armor, Hair, Eyes, Skin, Clothes, Species, Type, Accessories) {
        this.name = Name;
        this.strength = Strength;
    this.speed = Speed;
    this.intelligence = Intelligence;
    this.reflexes = Reflexes;
    this.age = Age;
    this.height = Height;
    this.weight = Weight;
    this.weapon = Weapon;
    this.usesMagic = UsesMagic;
    this.magicType = MagicType;
    this.armor = Armor;
    this.hair = Hair;
    this.eyes = Eyes;
    this.skin = Skin;
    this.clothes = Clothes;
    this.species = Species;
    this.type = Type;
    if (Accessories) {
            this.accessories = Accessories;
    }
    characters.charList[characters.charList.length] = Name;
}

characters.Xantar = new Character('Xantar', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'sword', true, 'derp', [], 'hair is brown\?', 'duh', 'foo', [], 'animale', 'wolf', []);
alert(characters.Xantar.weapon + '   ' + characters[0].type);

//Activate mainloop and get value for pausing purposes
var mainloopInterval = setInterval(mainloop, 5);
//Main game loop
function mainloop(){

}
```

The program seems to stop at:

```
characters.charList = [];
```

I simply don't see the problem here. Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<canvas id='canvas' style='border:1px solid black;'>Your browser does not support canvas. Please update your browser.</canvas>
```

Note: I am running this on JSFiddle.
If anyone could help me here, I would be really grateful.
Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/q6vdph1p/14/.

Comment: please share the jsfiddle link

Comment: As a side note, using an uppercase first letter for variables is an anti-pattern and can lead to clashes with class names `Type` could well be a class of its own

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: You might also want to consider not having `charList` inside `characters` at all, as much would break if a character named "charList" suddenly appeared. Where to properly put things would be a matter of what you intend to have in `charList` and `characters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted before, you need to assign an object to your `characters` variable before you'll be able to access properties in it.

Just declaring it with `var characters;` will assign it the value of `undefined` and trying to access `undefined.charList` and assign an empty array to it will fail.

A more proper, fail resistant, and readable way of declaring it would be building the empty data structure, like so:

```
var characters = {
    charList: []
};
```

Also, adding to the end of an array is more safe using `array.push()` than indexing by `array.length`, i.e.

```
characters.charList.push(Name);
```

rather than

```
characters.charList[characters.charList.length] = Name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! (Although I had thought of array.push();).

Comment: You're welcome :) using methods like `push()` just makes it much easier to see what is actually going on in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Need to set it as an object `var characters = {};`

Answer (score 2):

1. Variable "characters" must be an object. `var characters = {};`
2. charList should not be initialized with "var" keyword because it's not a new variable so it's just `characters.charList = [];`
3. On row 42 it's not `characters[0].type` but `characters.Xantar.type`
   [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q6vdph1p/15/)

Comment: Actually, I was testing the characters.charList array, so I meant to do characters[characters.charList[0]].type, and I was just testing characters.charList with var, just in case. That wasn't permanent. But thanks anyways!