# Element not updating with the current player action

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have another problem with my game (the same one from this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114505/game-code-breaking-when-setting-variable)**). The p element is not updating with the current player action. Here is the code (**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Feathercrown/h4vn1bgv/9/)**):

**HTML**

```
<canvas id='canvas'>Your browser does not support the canvas element.</canvas>
<p id='lol'>Action</p>
```

**CSS**

```
#canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
//Get canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Capture keypresses
var keys = [];
document.onKeyDown = function (e) {keys[e.keyCode] = true;};
document.onKeyUp = function (e) {keys[e.keyCode] = false;};

//Set game variables
var characters = {
    charList: []
};
var player = {
    character: 'none',
    currentAction: 'none',
    health: '100',
    energy: '100',
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    dx: 0,
    dy: 0,
    facing: 'right'
};

//Character constructor
function Character (Name, Strength, Speed, Intelligence, Reflexes, Age, Height, Weight, Weapon, UsesMagic, MagicType, Armor, Hair, Eyes, Skin, Clothes, Species, Type, Accessories) {
    this.name = Name;
    this.strength = Strength;
    this.speed = Speed;
    this.intelligence = Intelligence;
    this.reflexes = Reflexes;
    this.age = Age;
    this.height = Height;
    this.weight = Weight;
    this.weapon = Weapon;
    this.usesMagic = UsesMagic;
    this.magicType = MagicType;
    this.armor = Armor;
    this.hair = Hair;
    this.eyes = Eyes;
    this.skin = Skin;
    this.clothes = Clothes;
    this.species = Species;
    this.type = Type;
    if (Accessories) {
            this.accessories = Accessories;
    }
    characters.charList.push(Name);
}

characters.Xantar = new Character('Xantar', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'sword', true, 'derp', [], 'hair is brown\?', 'duh', 'foo', [], 'animale', 'wolf', []);
alert(characters.Xantar.weapon + '   ' + characters[characters.charList[0]].type);

//Activate mainloop and get value for pausing purposes
var mainloopInterval = setInterval(mainloop, 5);
//Main game loop
function mainloop(){
    //Allow player to do actions
    if(player.currentAction == 'none' || player.currentAction == 'jump'){
        if(keys[38]){
            player.currentAction == 'jump';
            player.dy = -10;
        }
        if(keys[32]){ //space
            if(keys[65]){ //a
                if(keys[68]){ //d
                    if(keys[83]){ //s
                        player.currentAction = 'asdAttack';
                    } else {
                        player.currentAction = 'adAttack';
                    }
                } else if(keys[83]){
                    player.currentAction = 'asAttack';
                } else {
                    player.currentAction = 'aAttack';
                }
            } else if(keys[68]){
                if(keys[83]){
                    player.currentAction = 'dsAttack';
                } else {
                    player.currentAction = 'dAttack';
                }
            } else if(keys[83]){
                player.currentAction = 'sAttack';
            } else{
                player.currentAction = 'spaceAttack';
            }
        }
    } else {
        //Action handling
    }
    document.getElementById('lol').innerHTML = player.currentAction;
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your question? The `p` element clearly updates from `Action` to `none` after the alert?

Comment: The p element is supposed to change to something else when you press a key.

Comment: That's because you're using `document.onKeyDown` instead of `document.onkeydown`. Case matters.

Comment: Thanks so much! I just ran into the onKeyDown vs onkeydown problem a while ago with a different code snippet, but I totally forgot :/

Comment: Also keep in mind that `player.currentAction == 'jump';` inside of `if(keys[38]){` won't do anything. You need to use `=` for setting a variable/property. `==` is comparison. If you wonder what I did I put a console.log inside of the `onKeyDown` handler and found out it wasn't executing at all, looked up the documentation and compared the two to find the mistake.

Comment: Oops. That one was a typo.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You're using the following key handlers:

```
document.onKeyDown = function (e) { keys[e.keyCode] = true;};
document.onKeyUp = function (e) { keys[e.keyCode] = false;};
```

If you try to print out some debug info you can see that nothing is ever happening:

```
document.onKeyDown = function (e) { 
    console.log('down', e.keyCode); // Will never show itself
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
};

document.onKeyUp = function (e) { 
    console.log('up', e.keyCode); // Will never show itself
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
};
```

This is because, as per the documentation for the events [onkeydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeydown) and [onkeyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup), they have to be spelled with all lowercase.

Hence the fix is to lowercase it:

```
document.onkeydown = function (e) { keys[e.keyCode] = true;};
document.onkeyup = function (e) { keys[e.keyCode] = false;};
//         ^  ^ Lowercase them!
```

[**Fixed JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/h4vn1bgv/13/)

**Note**:

As I mentioned in the comments

```
if(keys[38]){
    player.currentAction == 'jump';
    player.dy = -10;
}
```

won't set `player.currentAction.` You need to use `=`:

```
if(keys[38]){
    player.currentAction = 'jump';
    //                   ^ set it instead of comparing it
    player.dy = -10;
}
```